# How to increase OPCODE gas Price in Hyperledger Besu

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, private, besu, hyperledger

I want to setup Private POA blockchain using hyperledger besu. I dont want people to deploy smart contract on the chain. I searched on google and found it some alternative solution to increase `create` `OPCODE` gas price. But i dont know how to change `OPCODE` gas price Does anyone suggest it where should i change the gas price or does anyone have better solution?

Comment: If you use RPC, you could add a front http filter that would reject tx with contract creation payload on sendRawTx method. Requires that you decode it first.